# R-Markdown how to dispaly code in a PDF with only map and not all other results

Tags: r

It is my first time using R Markdown and I am trying to knit my PDF. I would like to hide everything which is in the console apart from the map which is produced. So I just want the code and the map in the PDF.

I have tried to use "message = FALSE,warning=FALSE" but this doesn't solve the problem. As seen by the picture below I would like to remove the circled area from the data

[enter image description here][1]

```
library("sp")
library("rgdal")
library("rgeos")
library("tmap")
library("spgwr")



Census.Data <-read.csv("worksheet_data/Southwark/practical_data_Southwark.csv")
# Load the output area shapefiles
Output.Areas<- readOGR("worksheet_data/Southwark/shapefiles", "Southwark_oa11")

# join our census data to the shapefile
OA.Census <- merge(Output.Areas, Census.Data, by.x="OA11CD", by.y="OA")

#Set the coordinate system to the British National Grid
proj4string(OA.Census) <- CRS("+init=epsg:27700")

#Data=polygonshapefile
#Dependent= Dependent variabable of shapefile
#Independent1= Explantory variable 1 
#Independent2= Explantory variable 2



GWR_map <- function(Data,dependent,independent1,independent2){
  GWRbandwidth <- gwr.sel(Data[[dependent]] ~ Data[[independent1]] + Data[[independent2]], data= Data, adapt = T)  
  GWR.model = gwr(Data[[dependent]] ~ Data[[independent1]] + Data[[independent2]], data= Data, adapt=GWRbandwidth, hatmatrix=TRUE, se.fit=TRUE)
  GWR.model
  results_GWR.model<-as.data.frame(GWR.model$SDF)
  names(results_GWR.model)
  GWR.map<- Data
  GWR.map@data<- cbind(Data@data, as.matrix(results_GWR.model))
  
  map1<- tm_shape(GWR.map) + tm_fill("localR2", n = 5, style = "quantile",  palette = "Blues")  + tm_layout(frame = TRUE, legend.text.size = 1.2, legend.title.size = 1.5, bg.color = "grey85")
  map1
}


GWR_map(OA.Census,"Qualification", "Unemployed", "White_British")


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFhLw.png
```

Comment: It's hard to know without knowing if  what you want to hide are messages, warnings, or something else.  RMarkdown has chunk options to hide most things.

Comment: Hard to be certain without access to your data, but you most likely want to set `message = FALSE`, and perhaps even `warning = FALSE` in your chunk options.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it works if you include `verbose=FALSE` in the function producing the unnecessary messages

in your case, you might try

```
Output.Areas<- readOGR("worksheet_data/Southwark/shapefiles", "Southwark_oa11", verbose=FALSE)
```